# synchronized method in for loop

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

In the following simple example code (mainly taken from this [nice udemy video](https://www.udemy.com/java-multithreading/#/lecture/108950)) there are two threads that increment a count instance variable through a `synchronized` method.

This method however is inside a `for` loop in each thread.

My question is: In a case like that, is it possible that the threads actually intermingle their calls to `increment`? For example something like:

> Thread 1 calls increment for i = 0
>
> Thread 1 calls increment for i = 1
>
> Thread 2 calls increment for j = 0
>
> Thread 2 calls increment for j = 1
>
> Thread 1 calls increment for i = 2
>
> Thread 2 calls increment for j = 2
>
> ... and so on

I tried running it many times for large `i`'s and `j`'s, but they always show sequentially, i.e.

> Thread 1 calls increment for i = 0
>
> Thread 1 calls increment for i = 1
>
> Thread 1 calls increment for i = 2
>
> ... Thread 1 finishes
>
> Thread 2 calls increment for j = 0
>
> Thread 2 calls increment for j = 1
>
> ... Thread 2 finishes

Based on my understanding on the `synchronized` keyword, the first case should happen, so I am just wondering if I am seeing the second case due to chance of there is something else that I am missing.

```
 public class SyncTest {

    private int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SyncTest test = new SyncTest ();
        test.doWork();
    }

    public synchronized void increment(String threadName) {
        System.out.println("thread: " + threadName);
        count++;
    }

    public void doWork() {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                    increment("t1");
                }
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public  void run() {
                for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
                    increment("t2");
                }
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Count is: " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: This example is correct, why do you think it would work wrong? `synchronized` guards the entire function body so this function is called sequentially.

Comment: My guess is that the first thread finishes before the second is even started. How long does the entire program run? Also, your listed output does not match the posted program.

Comment: "This method however is inside a for loop"  The method is _called_ from inside a for loop.  The method is _defined_ at top level in the SyncTest class.

Comment: "is it possible that the threads actually intermingle their calls to increment?"  That is the purpose of threads.  The threads run independently of one another except when they access shared variables (e.g., `count` in your example), and when they `synchronize` with one another (e.g., when your threads call `increment()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Based on my understanding on the synchronized keyword, the first case should happen, so I am just wondering if I am seeing the second case due to chance of there is something else that I am missing.

Your understanding is correct.

In fact, when I run your exact code, I get a sequence of `t1`s followed by a sequence of `t2`s, then `t1`s again, then `t2`s and so on. This clearly demonstrates that the threads are preempting each other and there's no subtle unintended synchronization that we're overlooking.